# Android spinner not displaying items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I was working with android application and a simple spinner is behaving like a freak.

I am trying to populate a spinner dynamically, and the spinner simply doesn't show me the list of the elements. All I see is the first element selected in the spinner.

```
private String[] cSpinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_s_details);

        this.cSpinner = new String[] {
                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
        };

        Spinner cName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbCName);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cSpinner);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cName.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Here is what my spinner looks like :

```
<Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cmbCName"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:clickable="false" />
```

What is going wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem!

```
android:clickable="false" --> Source of the problem

<Spinner
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/cmbCName"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
     android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try your adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, android.R.id.text1, cSpinner)
```

i hope it will work.